# Función para regresión en dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Quiero crear una función para crear una tabla con los diferentes pendientes de regresión de una tabla pero me genera un error. El código es el siguiente:

```
 def get(tickers):
    def penda(ticker):
        x=sm.add_constant(ln_new.index)
        y=ln_new[ticker]
        result=sm.OLS(y,x).fit()
        return (((math.exp(result.params[1]))**250)-1)*(result.rsquared)
    datas = map (tickers,penda)
    return(pd.concat(datas, keys=tickers, names=['Ticker', 'Date']))

 tickers = ['AALB.AS','ARL.DE']
 datar=ln_new
 all_data=get(tickers)
```

Y el error que genera es:

> ```
>    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    <ipython-input-45-633e7f285d08> in <module>
>        10 tickers = ['AALB.AS','ARL.DE']
>        11 datar=ln_new
>    ---> 12 all_data=get(tickers)
>    <ipython-input-45-633e7f285d08> in get(tickers)
>        5         result=sm.OLS(y,x).fit()
>        6         return (((math.exp(result.params[1]))**250)-1)*(result.rsquared)
>    ----> 7     datas = map (tickers,penda)
>        8     return(pd.concat(datas, keys=tickers, names=['Ticker', 'Date']))
>        9 
>    TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
> ```

¿Alguien qué me eche una mano?

Comment: ¿No debería ser `map(penda, tickers)`?

Comment: Por otro lado, he editado el código para arreglar la indentación. Verifica que ahora está correcta.